# Boost property_tree error: conversion of data to type "j" failed when getting an element in a .ini file

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-propertytree, istringstream

I have a .ini file contains below data

```
[SYSTEM]
num_of_vps = 1
```

And I have this code to read an element in .ini file. (`uint` defined as `typedef unsigned int uint`)

```
boost::property_tree::ptree pt; 
boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini(iniFilePath, pt);
hwCount = pt.get<uint>("SYSTEM.num_of_vps");
```

I created a from files including above code and called it in a wrapper function in `main.cc` file. Then I am getting below error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost_1_68_0::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost_1_68_0::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost_1_68_0::property_tree::ptree_bad_data> >'
> what():  conversion of data to type "j" failed
> stack trace

```
#12 0x00002aaab613fcd5 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#13 0x00002aaab9b29315 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at ../../../../src/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#14 0x00002aaab9a9e8f6 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>) at ../../../../src/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:47
#15 0x00002aaab9a9e941 in std::terminate () at ../../../../src/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:57
#16 0x00002aaab9a9ea74 in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=<optimized out>, tinfo=0x2aaab9e1ff60 <typeinfo for boost_1_68_0::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost_1_68_0::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost_1_68_0::property_tree::ptree_bad_data> >>, dest=0x2aaab99bef18 <boost_1_68_0::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost_1_68_0::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost_1_68_0::property_tree::ptree_bad_data> >::~clone_impl()>) at ../../../../src/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:93
#17 0x00002aaab99bec82 in boost_1_68_0::throw_exception<boost_1_68_0::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost_1_68_0::property_tree::ptree_bad_data> > (e=...) at throw_exception.hpp:72
#18 0x00002aaab99be576 in boost_1_68_0::exception_detail::throw_exception_<boost_1_68_0::property_tree::ptree_bad_data> (x=..., current_function=0x2aaab9b45fc0 <boost_1_68_0::enable_if<boost_1_68_0::property_tree::detail::is_translator<boost_1_68_0::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, unsigned int> >, unsigned int>::type boost_1_68_0::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::get_value<unsigned int, boost_1_68_0::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, unsigned int> >(boost_1_68_0::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, unsigned int>) const::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__> "typename boost_1_68_0::enable_if<boost_1_68_0::property_tree::detail::is_translator<Translator>, Type>::type boost_1_68_0::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key, Data, KeyCompare>::get_value(T"..., file=0x2aaab9b45830 "property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp", line=675) at throw_exception.hpp:89
#19 0x00002aaab99be01e in boost_1_68_0::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::get_value<unsigned int, boost_1_68_0::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, unsigned int> > (this=0xbc86c8, tr=...) at property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:673
#20 0x00002aaab99bd6a5 in boost_1_68_0::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::get_value<unsigned int> (this=0xbc86c8) at property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:683
#21 0x00002aaab99bc545 in boost_1_68_0::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::get<unsigned int> (this=0x7fffffff9470, path=...) at property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:754
#22 0x00002aaab99bba83 in MyRT::DUTConfigFile::readIniFile (this=0xbc5d50, iniFilePath=...) at DUTConfigFile.cpp:231
#23 0x00002aaab99ba8d2 in MyRT::DUTConfigFile::DUTConfigFile (this=0xbc5d50, iniFilePath=..., configFilePath=...) at DUTConfigFile.cpp:26
#24 0x00002aaab99c0839 in setupMyConfigs () at SimXLInterface.cpp:83
#31 0x0000000000408847 in main ()
```

I tried gdb and it is throwing an exception when converting string to uint using istringstream. Below are the two types of the transition

```
template<class K, class D, class C>                                                                                                                    
template<class Type> inline                                                                                                                            
Type basic_ptree<K, D, C>::get_value() const
{
    return get_value<Type>(
        typename translator_between<data_type, Type>::type());
}

(gdb) p typeid(Type).name()
$2 = 0x2aaab5c33c91 <typeinfo name for unsigned int> "j"
(gdb) p typeid(data_type).name()
could not find typeinfo symbol for 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
```

Below function in `basic_ios.h` throws a `__throw_bad_cast()` exception (here `this->_M_num_get = NULL`)

```
const __num_get_type& __ng = __check_facet(this->_M_num_get);
```

Internal build automation Makefile is addding `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to object file creation by default

```
g++ -I/usr/myboost/boost/boost -Wall -std=c++14 -fopenmp -m64 -msse2 -fPIC \
  -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -g -o *.o -fPIC -c *.cpp
```

.so building command

```
g++ -m64 -msse2 -pthread -shared -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  \
  -Wl,-znoexecstack -g -o runtime.so *.o -ldl -lrt -lz -fopenmp -lcrypto
```

If I change it to read a std::string type and later convert it to uint, it is working without an exception

```
std::string strHwCount = pt.get<std::string>("SYSTEM.num_of_vps");
hwCount = static_cast<uint>(std::stoul(strHwCount));
```

I am using `boost-1.68` and `gcc-7.3`. Dose this have to do with the `ABI` macro that I'm using? Is there a way to resolve this without above workaround

---

### UPDATE

First of all I am migrating project from cmake to a internal custom build automation (some enhanced version of Makefile). In cmake this worked fine. Based on sehe's answer I did some further analysis.
In a small standalone example this error is not reproducible (using both local string and actual .ini file read).

When going through gdb, In file `boost/property_tree/stream_translator.hpp`, I could find the read value from the file (changed to `num_of_vps = 4` in file) in the both `string` and `istringstream`.

```
optional<Type> basic_ptree<K, D, C>
    ::get_value_optional(Translator tr) const
{
    return tr.get_value(data());
}

(gdb) p data()
$1 = "4"

boost_1_68_0::optional<E> get_value(const internal_type &v) {
    std::basic_istringstream<Ch, Traits, Alloc> iss(v);
    iss.imbue(m_loc);
    E e;
    customized::extract(iss, e);
    ....
}

(gdb) p v
$1 = "4"
(gdb) p iss.str()
$2 = "4"
```

Inside above `customized::extract(iss, e)` function there is a `string` to `unsigned int` conversion using a `basic_istream`

```
static void extract(std::basic_istream<Ch, Traits>& s, E& e) {
    s >> e;
    if(!s.eof()) { s >> std::ws; }
}
```

Inside this `>>` operator there is a `_M_extract` function and inside that `__check_facet` function throws the exception (by cheking NULL of `this->_M_num_get` )

```
basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::
_M_extract(_ValueT& __v) {
  __try {
    const __num_get_type& __ng = __check_facet(this->_M_num_get);
    ...

inline const _Facet&
__check_facet(const _Facet* __f) {
  if (!__f)
    __throw_bad_cast();
  return *__f;
}
```

stack trace above scenario

```
#0  std::istream::_M_extract<unsigned int>(unsigned int&) (__f=0x0) at gcc-7.3.0/objdir/x86_64-centos-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_ios.h:49
#1  std::istream::operator>>(unsigned int&) (this=0x7fffffff9980, __n=@0x7fffffff997c: 0)
#2  boost_1_68_0::property_tree::customize_stream::extract(std::istream&, unsigned int&) (s=..., e=@0x7fffffff997c: 0)
#3  boost_1_68_0::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, unsigned int>::get_value(std::string const&) (this=0x7fffffff9b58, v="4")
```

I could see the same behavior in the another place that we are using `std::stringstream` . Variable `ss` shows empty even with `<<` operator adding strings

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << firmId;
```

I had a concern about that the `ABI` flag causing this, but I was able to remove it and the issue is still there. I searched about this kind of `istream` issues but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: What is `unit`? There is not such a standard type in C++.

Comment: As I mentioned above its just `unsigned int` (`typedef unsigned int uint`)

Comment: Oh these are horrible. Thanks for documenting it so well. It does eliminate a myriad questions to be asked before doubting the input bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a tweak to the gcc command I was able to run the executable with the `.so` with all `sstream` usages. Previously the gcc linking command was

```
g++ -m64 -msse2 -pthread -shared -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  \
  -Wl,-znoexecstack -g -o runtime.so *.o -ldl -lrt -lz -fopenmp -lcrypto
```

Removing `-static-libstdc++` and dynamically linking `libstdc++.so` worked

```
g++ -m64 -msse2 -pthread -shared -static-libgcc -Wl,-znoexecstack -o runtime.so *.o \
  -fPIC -ldl -lrt -lz -fopenmp -lcrypto -Wl,-rpath,/depot/gcc-7.3.0/lib64
```

Answer (score 4):

Your input is corrupt. Likely it's using an encoding or code-points that you didn't expect, but don't stand out for a human reader.

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b03dee663c35ad9e)

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"([SYSTEM]
num_of_vps = 1)");
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    read_ini(iss, pt);

    uint hwCount = pt.get<uint>("SYSTEM.num_of_vps"); 

    std::cout << "hwCount: " << hwCount << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
hwCount: 1
```

However, if you change the input to be e.g.

```
    std::istringstream iss(R"([SYSTEM]
num_of_vps = 1)");
```

(Note that the space after `=` is now `< > 160, \240, U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE, ^KNS, &nbsp;`) it prints:

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4f76a2cb4c2ee65)

Prints

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data>'
  what():  conversion of data to type "j" failed
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on your answer, I did some further analysis, please see the update.

Comment: That means the global locale you're using doesn't have the required numeric facets. If this is on another installation than the Cmake one that works I suspect an installation issue (sometimes eg. minimalist containers come without locale definitions, or your environment refers to a locale that use not available).

Comment: Hi, I found a workaround by removing `-static-libstdc++` from the linking command `g++ -m64 -msse2 -pthread -shared -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-znoexecstack -g -o runtime.so *.o -ldl -lrt -lz -fopenmp -lcrypto` and added dynamic linking of `libstdc++.so`. I still couldn't understand the reason for this

Comment: @NalakaRajamanthri well, whatever the mechanics, the reason will rhyme with "The static library doesn't have (access to) the proper locale definition data"

Comment: However your finding is so useful, it may be worth putting an answer with that information - [SO] policy is that comments are "temporary content" that may get lost in the future.